# Getting duplicates on JOINs in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

**My Tables:**

Account A
Plate P
FinTransMaster F
TollTrans T

**Relationships:**

```
A.AccountId = P.AccountId  
A.AccountId = F.AccountId  
A.AccountId = P.AccountId = F.AccountId  
P.LicPlateNo = T.LicPlateNo  

T.AccountId != A.AccountId  
T.AccountId != P.AccountId  
T.AccountId != F.AccountId
```

I need all records where:

```
     T.AccountId = '123456'   
 AND EXISTS F.TransCode = 'TOLL'   
 AND NOT EXISTS F.TransCode = 'PYMT'
 AND A.CurrentBalance > 0
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT A.*

FROM Account A
INNER JOIN Plate P ON P.AccountId = A.AccountId
INNER JOIN TollTrans T ON T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo

WHERE EXISTS     (SELECT 1
                  FROM FinTransMaster F
                  WHERE F.AcctID = A.AccountID AND F.TransCode = 'TOLL'
                  ) 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM FinTransMaster F
                  WHERE F.AcctID = A.AccountID AND F.TransCode = 'PYMT'
                  )
  AND T.AccountId = '123456'
  AND A.CurrentBalance > 0

ORDER BY BalanceDT DESC
```

Each Account has a Licence Plate. Some Accounts have multiple Licence Plates. Maybe, that's the reason **I'm getting duplicates.**

How can I refine this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in the Account table, just move the other tables to EXISTS subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM Account A
WHERE EXISTS     (SELECT 1
                  FROM FinTransMaster F
                  WHERE F.AcctID = A.AccountID AND F.TransCode = 'TOLL'
                  ) 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM FinTransMaster F
                  WHERE F.AcctID = A.AccountID AND F.TransCode = 'PYMT'
                  )
  AND EXISTS      (SELECT 1
                  FROM Plate P
                  INNER JOIN TollTrans T ON T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo
                  WHERE P.AccountId = A.AccountId
                    AND T.AccountId = '123456'
                  )
  AND A.CurrentBalance > 0
ORDER BY BalanceDT DESC
```

If `BalanceDT` isn't in the Account table, then you can't do that, but, well, you didn't qualify that column.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
select distinct a.col1,a.col2....
(rest of the query)
```

Also see if you can replace join with exists as you are not selecting anything from other tables, so performance would be better.

Answer (score 2):

you can remove with distinct

```
SELECT distinct A.*
FROM Account A
INNER JOIN Plate P ON P.AccountId = A.AccountId
INNER JOIN TollTrans T ON T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo
INNER JOIN FinTransMaster F on F.AcctID = A.AccountID AND F.TransCode = 'TOLL'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM FinTransMaster G
                  WHERE G.AcctID = A.AccountID AND G.TransCode = 'PYMT'
                  )
AND T.AccountId = '123456' AND A.CurrentBalance > 0
ORDER BY BalanceDT DESC
```